# Log file rollover

Tags: shell

I have a custom script running , I want to redirect the output and few execution stages of the script to a log file.

My requirement is - When the log file exceeds 20 MB of size , I will the move the contents to a new file and my script recreates the logfile. At anytime I will have one backup of the recent log contents. I tried to come up with the below logic:

```
if [  -e "$logfile" ]

then

    logsize=ls -l $logfile |awk '{print $5}'

    ls -l $logfile |awk '{print $5}'

    if [ "$logsize" -gt 2097152 ]

    then

        mv $logfile $(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M").log

        touch $logfile

    fi

else

    touch $logfile

fi
```

I would like to get the experts thoughts and if there is any other efficient way to do this task plz let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `logrotate` command instead or building a custom script.

Have a read to this [guide](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl8_logrota.htm)

A sample configuration for your requirements would be like this:

```
/var/log/logfile {
   missingok
   size 20M       
   rotate 5
```

}

Comment: Thanks Ander2 for your input